# Complex geometry formulas

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Today I tried to understand the formulas for complex geometry couldn't find the proofs. Where can I find the proofs?(especially perpendicularity, concyclic criteria, directed angles and triangles explanations).
Also, I tried to use the formula $A,B,C,D $ are concylic iff $\frac{b-a}{c-a} ÷ \frac{b-d}{c-d} \in \mathbb{R}$ to prove the statement below, but I obtained the value of $\frac{4i+1}{5}$. Are the points just not concyclic?
Prove that $ABCD$ is cyclic, where $A (3 - 2i), B (2-i), C (-2 + 3i), D (1 - 2i)$

Comment: Show your solution by editing the question.

Comment: Your computation is correct and A,B,C,D are NOT concylic. As regards proofs see https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/cmplx/en-cmplx.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Note that point $B$ is on $\overline{AD}$. The graph is below (in the Cartesian, not complex plane):

[image]

No matter how you connect the points, the "quadrilateral" is equivalent to either a triangle or two triangles with one common point. Since all triangles are cyclic, this "quadrilateral" is cyclic.

-FruDe